# QWidget::nativeEvent can't get correct message in Qt 5.11

Tags: qt

Before Qt 5.11, the following code works fine.

```
bool MyQDialogSubclass::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result) {
    MSG* msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if(msg->message == WM_NCACTIVATE) {
        emit ncActive((bool)(msg->wParam));
    }
    return QWidget::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);
}
```

But in Qt 5.11 if I try to get some native message, the value of msg->message will always be some large numbers like 16886792, which is supposed to be something small like 0x0086(WM_NCACTIVATE).

The debug window shows something like this
[debug capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPSQ7.png)

I tested my project on Windows 10 17134 64bit.

I've done some research but still have no clue.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did your research include looking into Qt source code (assuming that documentation revealed nothing much)? You’d need to look at the code that invokes the native event filter.

Comment: @KubaOber I did my best looking into those files but I'm afraid I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Just to be sure -- you do need to test the event type. `msg` is only a valid message when `eventType` is `"windows_dispatcher_MSG"`. But that may not be the only problem. You'd need to show a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Most likely, your build is somehow binary-incompatible with your version of Qt. So try deleting the build folder and re-building -- and make sure that the Qt kit and version are set up correctly and use the correct compiler.

Comment: @KubaOber Event type is correct (windows_generic_MSG), and I am not the only one who has this problem. I see at least two people on the Internet complaining about this and they all think this is a Qt bug. This code works fine in Qt 5.9 on the same operating system (Just confirmed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is a bug in Qt 5.11.1 and fixed in 5.11.2 and there is a workaround for it:

```
#if (QT_VERSION == QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 11, 1))
MSG* msg = *reinterpret_cast<MSG**>(message);
#else
MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
#endif
```

check Qt forum :
https://forum.qt.io/topic/93141/qtablewidget-itemselectionchanged/13

Comment: Just for reference, the bug is tracked at [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69074](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69074]